# javascript multicookies

Tags: javascript, cookie

После обновления страници, назначена только первая кука, 
client_user_site_id= ид_юзера;
остальные все не назначаются, как и время сессии.
Подскажите, в чем беда?

```js
 var user = 'client_user_site_id=' + user_id + '; ',
    atp = 'atp_user_email=' + user_email + '; ',
    client_admin = 'clientroom_admin=' + user_email + '; ',
    map = 'map_watcher=' + user_email + '; ',
    path = 'path=/;',
    CookieDate = new Date,
    cookieLife = 'expires=' + CookieDate.setFullYear(CookieDate.getFullYear() + 1) + ';',
    cookie_full = user + atp + client_admin + map + cookieLife + path;

    document.cookie = cookie_full;
    location.reload(); // обновление страницы



апр
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _Подскажите, в чем беда?_ - судя по всему - неверный формат

Comment: как оказалось, не совсем. кукисы хранятся в формате : client_user_site_id%3DИДШКА%3Batp_user_email%3DПОЧТА%3B. То есть, символ = закодирован в %3D, а точка с запятой в %3B. ошибку нашел, но пока не нашел решения

Comment: что именно ты хочешь сделать? это у тебя должны быть три разных куки или одна большая?

Comment: @Grundy в идеале мне нужно много кук, так как наличие куки является доступом к разным страницам сайта, наличие куки дает доступ, значение в ней - служит переменной для просчета выводимых данных на самой странице. Когда роль пользователя одна( одна кука ) все работает, в противном случае получаю эту строку.( с защитой типа if (isset($_COOKIE['client_user_site_id'])) {
} else { exit('Авторизируйтесь на сайте.') ; }                                                понял только, что моя строка с куками преобразуется с помощью encodeURIComponent. попробую по другому ее назначать или декод. при получ

Comment: @Grundy  код на странице по закрытому доступу : if (isset($_COOKIE['client_user_site_id'])) { } else { exit('Авторизируйтесь на сайте.') ; }

Answer (score 0):

Так как нужно записать *четыре* значения, нужно *четыре* раза вызывать сеттер, так как он рассчитан только на [добавление/изменение одиночной записи](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Таким образом код должен быть преобразован либо к ручному вызову присваивания, либо сделать то же самое в цикле.

Например так:

```
var user = 'client_user_site_id=' + user_id + '; ',
    atp = 'atp_user_email=' + user_email + '; ',
    client_admin = 'clientroom_admin=' + user_email + '; ',
    map = 'map_watcher=' + user_email + '; ',
    path = 'path=/;',
    CookieDate = new Date,
    cookieLife = 'expires=' + CookieDate.setFullYear(CookieDate.getFullYear() + 1) + ';';

[user, atp, client_admin, map].forEach(
    cookie => document.cookie = `${cookie}${path}${cookieLife}`
);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Примерно там и сделал, приибегнув к помощи
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework 
docCookies.setItem("map_watcher", "yes", Infinity);